# Modern OpenGL : Draw a sphere and cylinder

Tags: opengl, graphics

I've learned how to draw a cube using OpenGL from various tutorials.

For a cube, we consider each face to be composed of two triangles, and then appropriately set up the vertex and color buffers. These buffers are then sent to the shader code.

How do we similarly draw a sphere and cylinder? All tutorials online focus on drawing cubes.

Setting up vertex buffer for a sphere or cylinder doesn't seem trivial; I'm unable to "construct" them from triangles as we do for cubes.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some code that I use when drawing spheres.

Note: This code uses C++, with the GLM math library.

```
// Calc The Vertices
for (int i = 0; i <= Stacks; ++i){

    float V   = i / (float) Stacks;
    float phi = V * glm::pi <float> ();

    // Loop Through Slices
    for (int j = 0; j <= Slices; ++j){

        float U = j / (float) Slices;
        float theta = U * (glm::pi <float> () * 2);

        // Calc The Vertex Positions
        float x = cosf (theta) * sinf (phi);
        float y = cosf (phi);
        float z = sinf (theta) * sinf (phi);

        // Push Back Vertex Data
        vertices.push_back (glm::vec3 (x, y, z) * Radius);
    }
}

// Calc The Index Positions
for (int i = 0; i < Slices * Stacks + Slices; ++i){

    indices.push_back (i);
    indices.push_back (i + Slices + 1);
    indices.push_back (i + Slices);

    indices.push_back (i + Slices + 1);
    indices.push_back (i);
    indices.push_back (i + 1);
}
```

This algorithm creates what is called a UV Sphere.
The 'Slices' and 'Stacks' are the number of subdivisions on the X and Y axis.

Comment: It overflows index range.

Comment: Where does that occur?
The code never accesses any array elements, only adds to the array.

How can it overflow the index range if it is never accessed in the first place?

Comment: When `i=Slices*Stacks+Slices-1`, you push `i+Slices+1` to indices. Since you have total of `(Stacks+1)*(Slices+1)` vertices, when you have `Slices>Stacks`, the index of `i+Slices+1` will refer beyond the end of the set of vertices. This won't lead to UB in the C++ code, but will in the OpenGL code (`glDrawElements` et al.). In practice, you'll get random triangles sticking out of your sphere.

Comment: Ah, yes. I see what you mean. Strange that it never seemed to cause me any issues. Thank you.

Comment: @Ruslan I use the above code for rendering a ellipsoid. I have some strange issue. I read you answer but I have not understood how to fix it. Can you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60686457/issue-in-drawing-ellipsoid-with-opengl

Comment: @thewoz it's not my answer.

Comment: Hi @Ruslan I'm not specking about the replay of R_Finlay but about your note "When i=Slices*Stacks+Slices-1, you push i+Slices+1 to indices. Since you have total of (Stacks+1)*(Slices+1) vertices, when you have Slices>Stacks, the index of i+Slices+1 will refer beyond the end of the set of vertices. This won't lead to UB in the C++ code, but will in the OpenGL code (glDrawElements et al.). In practice, you'll get random triangles sticking out of your sphere"

Answer (score 1):

For cylinders, it is convenient to work in [cylindrical coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system#Cartesian_coordinates): (angle, radius, height). You will compute two polygons (constant angle increment, fixed radius, two height values) and create: two sets of triangles for the basis and a set of rectangles (split in two) for the lateral surface.

For spheres, you will use spherical coordinates: (inclination, elevation, radius). By varying the two angles (one at a time), you will describe parallels and meridians on the sphere. These define a meshing, such that every tile is a quadrilateral (except at the poles); split along a diagonal to get triangles.